# Где скачать Datastax Devcenter? или посоветуйте бесплатный gui клиент Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Не могу найти, где скачать Datastax Devecenter. На официальном сайте ссылки ведут на страницу с загрузкой Enterprise OpsCenter Docker и т.д.
Пробовал качать их, но ничего не нашёл. Может у кого-то остался архив или знает бесплатную альтернативу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Devcenter - это очень старый софт, новое название - Studio. И то и то можно скачать с https://academy.datastax.com/downloads (зарегистрировавшись).  Но хочется отметить что это не клиент для Cassandra, а для DSE, с [соответсвующей лицензией](https://www.datastax.com/enterprise-terms)... ([See FAQ](https://www.datastax.com/datastax-licensing-faqs#16))

Update in 2020th:

Для Cassandra, альтернативой является [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/), в составе которого есть интерпретатор для Cassandra. Я недавно делал презентацию на эту тему, вот [тут слайды](https://www.slideshare.net/alexott/zeppelin-apache-spark-cassandra-234718403), и там в описании есть ссылка на нотебуки и видео.